# Can anyone recommend a reliable multiport USB-C Hub?

Tags: usb, hub

Can anyone recommend a good USB-C multifunction hub for use with a 2018 MacBook Pro? It has to be bus-powered, have ethernet, SD card, HDMI, hopefully VGA as well, audio out, and at least 2 USB 3 ports. Most of the models available with all these ports on amazon are from no-name distributors:

Here are 3, which are obviously the same model:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GDHD3VC/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07GDHD3VC)

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GYBMQKD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07GYBMQKD)

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07HR6Z8VF/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07HR6Z8VF)

Oh, and this one, which is by a different manufacturer:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07DFNVWVB/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07DFNVWVB)

The OWC Travel Dock doesn't have enough ports, nor does the Kingston "Nucleum."

Comment: So, the only thing wrong with the products you listed is, that they come from a no-name manufacturer?

Comment: Well, that's one problem, but the other, more significant one is the number of complaints about them.

Comment: Big name doesn't necessarily mean reliable. My ASUS mini-dock that came with my laptop and costs 80$USD on official website failed after a year of use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [one from Lenovo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07FQBX53Z); it is also cheaper than the options you included.

If you are willing to drop the audio requirement, you can get it [even cheaper](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07919GQ4R) (without VGA).

I hope Lenovo is a reliable enough manufacturer for you.

Comment: Thanks, but Lenovo isn't its manufacturer. It is made by "Linxee (Beijing) Technology Co.,Ltd", only garners 3.5 stars on amazon, and frankly, is probably identical to the first three that I mention. Same price, too.

Comment: So the one in https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GYBMQKD/?tag=stackoverflow17-20 has only 5-star reviews; what's wrong with it then?

Comment: Well, it only has 10 reviews, and what's the warranty like on the device? I couldn't find anything. What's the customer service like?

Answer (score 0):

There is a UGreen USB-C dock, but it doesn't have a headphone jack:

https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32821301992.html

I have used a few UGreen products, such as DP cables, USB switcher and USB network card and they seem quite reliable and AliExpress rating of this product is high.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't have VGA, either. Since my original posting, I've found three more docks:

1. Hyperdrive. https://www.hypershop.com/collections/usb-c-hubs/products/hyperdrive-ultimate-usb-c-hub-for-macbook-pc-usb-c-devices
2. Cable Creation. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N3335FK/
3. Tripp Lite. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N9C5RP0/

The hub from Cable Creation looks identical to a differently-shaped variation of the #3 from TrippLite (ttps://www.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-Charging-Thunderbolt-U442-DOCK2-S/dp/B07CH9VXZ3), but Tripp Lite assures me that they designed theirs. Possible?

Comment: It is a normal practice for several chinese OEM's to have similar design and order components in bulk for several companies as it cuts costs, but then the assembly is done separately (even big OEM's like OPPO and OnePlus do that), so you will find a lot of same-looking hubs and should choose based on their reviews. The Hyperdrive https://www.amazon.com/HyperDrive-Adapter-Ultimate-Delivery-Charging/dp/B076515WSF seems more reliable. And I also found this one: https://aliexpress.com/item/Vention-USB-C-C-USB-3-0-Thunderbolt-3/32849364874.html

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the [Euasoo model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GDHD3VC) that you linked. I have used it across Desktop, Laptop, and Phone for almost a year now and it has worked great.

The name brands are unlikely to offer anything like what you want. The big fruit, would much rather sell 25 separate dongles that provide this functionality and charge $60 for each.